IClaimsTransformation not persisting added claims
I'm trying to add custom claims to my Blazor Server (.NET 8) application, for which I am using the IClaimsTransformation.
public class MyClaimsTransformation() : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (!principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "TEST"))
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("TEST", "TESTVALUE"));
        }

        return principal;
    }
}

The TransformAsync method gets called multiple times, which is apparently normal, according to other topics I found on stackoverflow.
However, I would expect the second call to the TransformAsync method it would already have the claim with type TEST. But it does not, I have to add the claim every single time.
Any idea what's going on here?
Note: I have found 2 ways of adding custom claims. One is by adding claims to the current identity, and the second is by adding a new identity. I have tried both, neither work.
Authentication is set up as follows, using OpenID Connect:
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/statuscode/401";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = configuration["Security:Authority"];
        options.MetadataAddress = configuration["Security:MetadataAddress"];
        options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
        options.ClientId = configuration["Security:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = configuration["Security:ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = configuration["Security:ResponseType"];
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.UsePkce = true;
    });


It seems to be the caching behavior of the ClaimsTransformation, Maybe you can refer to this link.

You can inject the IMemoryCache service in your ClaimsTransformer constructor.
public class MyClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
   private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

   public MyClaimsTransformation(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
   {
       _memoryCache = memoryCache;
   }

   public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
   {
       var userName = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

       if (userName != null && !_memoryCache.TryGetValue($"ClaimsAdded_{userName}", out bool claimsAdded))
       {
           if (!principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "TEST"))
           {
               var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
               identity.AddClaim(new Claim("TEST", "TESTVALUE"));

               // Set the cache entry for the user
               _memoryCache.Set($"ClaimsAdded_{userName}", true, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
               {
                   AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) // Cache duration
               });
           }
       }
       return principal;
   }       
}

Be sure register the services like below:
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformation>();

